# Extjs Form Validtion

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using Extjs Ext.form.FormPanel to create a form that will contain some fields like name, company,...,etc. Among the fields will be zip code and phone number, let's take the zip code problem, the zip code could be 5 numbers or 5 numbers plus 4 characters, I don't want to create two separate fields for the zip code, is there a way that I could create one field and prevent users from entering the zip code wrongly, just as the following jQuery plugin does:

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Answer (score 4):

ExtJS has [vtypes](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/adv-vtypes.html), that let you write validation code.

**Simpler:** `TextField`s have a `regex` configuration option that forces match on validation.
Your regex can be (assuming space separator then a-z only, case-insensitive):

```
/^\d{5}(? [a-z]{4})?$/i
```

Comment: Ok, that is fine, but that doesn't give me masked input which is easier for users, I found an extjs plugin called Cherry http://code.google.com/p/cherryonext/ that has masked input features but the size of the plugin is about 131KBH which is big, any other alternative?

Comment: haven't used any, but here is one that seems to implement that with ExtJS: http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=64797

Else you can use jQuery to do that on an Ext.form.TextField (use the input's id) and wrap it into a vtype.

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is to accept ZIP or ZIP+4, the regex format should be as follows:

```
/^\d{5}(?-\d{4})?$
```

The optional delimiter should be a dash, and the four "characters" should always be numbers.